# valgrind reports mkl's dsyev memory leak

Tags: c, linux, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm trying to use mkl's dsyev to calculate eigenvalues and vectors.
I found [this example from intel](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/dsyev_ex.c.htm).

It works but when I use valgrind to test it, it gives 1665 lines of errors.

It's too much so I'll post it at the end.

Most of them are uninitialized value(s), which don't matter as long as the result is right (correct me if I'm wrong). What concerns me is the memory leak showed by valgrind. I followed the example and used dsyev in my own program and valgrind acted the same way.

I'm afraid this will cause problem if my program is to run for a long time.

I in on Ubuntu 14.04, compiling with icc 13.1.1 with the -O0 option.

This is valgrind result (I don't know how to put all in format, you can only read the last few lines):

```
> ==13040== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
> ==13040== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
> ==13040== Command: ./a.out
> ==13040== 
> ==13040== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
> ==13040==    at 0x94278CD: mkl_lapack_ps_avx_xdlansy (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_avx.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x667F3C1: mkl_lapack_ps_xdlansy (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5C515F4: mkl_lapack_dlansy (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6ABEEEF: mkl_lapack_dsyev (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x4FCEC58: DSYEV (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x4010D0: main (in /home/usrname/virtualscreen/ConfLib/org/a.out)
> ==13040== 
> ==13040== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
> ==13040==    at 0x94278D3: mkl_lapack_ps_avx_xdlansy (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_avx.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x667F3C1: mkl_lapack_ps_xdlansy (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5C515F4: mkl_lapack_dlansy (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6ABEEEF: mkl_lapack_dsyev (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x4FCEC58: DSYEV (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x4010D0: main (in /home/usrname/virtualscreen/ConfLib/org/a.out)
> ==13040== 
> ==13040== Invalid read of size 16
> ==13040==    at 0x7899C68: __intel_sse2_strlen (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/compiler/lib/intel64/libiomp5.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x7845F52: __kmp_env_get (kmp_environment.c:127)
> ==13040==    by 0x785EF96: __kmp_register_library_startup() (kmp_runtime.c:7363)
> ==13040==    by 0x78601B4: __kmp_middle_initialize (kmp_runtime.c:7876)
> ==13040==    by 0x7847903: omp_get_num_procs (kmp_ftn_entry.h:497)
> ==13040==    by 0x5662F44: MKL_get_N_Cores (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5662E17: mkl_serv_get_max_threads (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5C6F94C: mkl_lapack_dorgql (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6A7A25C: mkl_lapack_dorgtr (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6ABF0D6: mkl_lapack_dsyev (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x4FCEC58: DSYEV (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x4010D0: main (in /home/usrname/virtualscreen/ConfLib/org/a.out)
> ==13040==  Address 0x8811440 is 48 bytes inside a block of size 58 alloc'd
> ==13040==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x8281C59: __add_to_environ (setenv.c:193)
> ==13040==    by 0x4C3277F: setenv (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x7846093: __kmp_env_set (kmp_environment.c:236)
> ==13040==    by 0x785EF8E: __kmp_register_library_startup() (kmp_runtime.c:7361)
> ==13040==    by 0x78601B4: __kmp_middle_initialize (kmp_runtime.c:7876)
> ==13040==    by 0x7847903: omp_get_num_procs (kmp_ftn_entry.h:497)
> ==13040==    by 0x5662F44: MKL_get_N_Cores (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5662E17: mkl_serv_get_max_threads (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5C6F94C: mkl_lapack_dorgql (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6A7A25C: mkl_lapack_dorgtr (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6ABF0D6: mkl_lapack_dsyev (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040== 
> ==13040== Invalid read of size 16
> ==13040==    at 0x7899C68: __intel_sse2_strlen (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/compiler/lib/intel64/libiomp5.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x78464B5: __kmp_env_blk_init (kmp_environment.c:536)
> ==13040==    by 0x786D5B8: __kmp_env_initialize(char const*) (kmp_settings.c:4866)
> ==13040==    by 0x7860419: __kmp_middle_initialize (kmp_runtime.c:7876)
> ==13040==    by 0x7847903: omp_get_num_procs (kmp_ftn_entry.h:497)
> ==13040==    by 0x5662F44: MKL_get_N_Cores (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5662E17: mkl_serv_get_max_threads (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5C6F94C: mkl_lapack_dorgql (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6A7A25C: mkl_lapack_dorgtr (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6ABF0D6: mkl_lapack_dsyev (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x4FCEC58: DSYEV (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x4010D0: main (in /home/usrname/virtualscreen/ConfLib/org/a.out)
> ==13040==  Address 0x8811440 is 48 bytes inside a block of size 58 alloc'd
> ==13040==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x8281C59: __add_to_environ (setenv.c:193)
> ==13040==    by 0x4C3277F: setenv (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x7846093: __kmp_env_set (kmp_environment.c:236)
> ==13040==    by 0x785EF8E: __kmp_register_library_startup() (kmp_runtime.c:7361)
> ==13040==    by 0x78601B4: __kmp_middle_initialize (kmp_runtime.c:7876)
> ==13040==    by 0x7847903: omp_get_num_procs (kmp_ftn_entry.h:497)
> ==13040==    by 0x5662F44: MKL_get_N_Cores (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5662E17: mkl_serv_get_max_threads (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5C6F94C: mkl_lapack_dorgql (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6A7A25C: mkl_lapack_dorgtr (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6ABF0D6: mkl_lapack_dsyev (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040== 
> ==13040== Invalid read of size 16
> ==13040==    at 0x7899C68: __intel_sse2_strlen (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/compiler/lib/intel64/libiomp5.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x7846557: __kmp_env_blk_init (kmp_environment.c:536)
> ==13040==    by 0x786D5B8: __kmp_env_initialize(char const*) (kmp_settings.c:4866)
> ==13040==    by 0x7860419: __kmp_middle_initialize (kmp_runtime.c:7876)
> ==13040==    by 0x7847903: omp_get_num_procs (kmp_ftn_entry.h:497)
> ==13040==    by 0x5662F44: MKL_get_N_Cores (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5662E17: mkl_serv_get_max_threads (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5C6F94C: mkl_lapack_dorgql (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6A7A25C: mkl_lapack_dorgtr (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6ABF0D6: mkl_lapack_dsyev (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x4FCEC58: DSYEV (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x4010D0: main (in /home/usrname/virtualscreen/ConfLib/org/a.out)
> ==13040==  Address 0x8811440 is 48 bytes inside a block of size 58 alloc'd
> ==13040==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x8281C59: __add_to_environ (setenv.c:193)
> ==13040==    by 0x4C3277F: setenv (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x7846093: __kmp_env_set (kmp_environment.c:236)
> ==13040==    by 0x785EF8E: __kmp_register_library_startup() (kmp_runtime.c:7361)
> ==13040==    by 0x78601B4: __kmp_middle_initialize (kmp_runtime.c:7876)
> ==13040==    by 0x7847903: omp_get_num_procs (kmp_ftn_entry.h:497)
> ==13040==    by 0x5662F44: MKL_get_N_Cores (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5662E17: mkl_serv_get_max_threads (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5C6F94C: mkl_lapack_dorgql (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6A7A25C: mkl_lapack_dorgtr (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6ABF0D6: mkl_lapack_dsyev (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040== 
> ==13040== Syscall param sched_setaffinity(mask) points to unaddressable byte(s)
> ==13040==    at 0x833B3E9: syscall (syscall.S:38)
> ==13040==    by 0x7882538: __kmp_affinity_determine_capable (z_Linux_util.c:385)
> ==13040==    by 0x786DB20: __kmp_env_initialize(char const*) (kmp_settings.c:4974)
> ==13040==    by 0x7860419: __kmp_middle_initialize (kmp_runtime.c:7876)
> ==13040==    by 0x7847903: omp_get_num_procs (kmp_ftn_entry.h:497)
> ==13040==    by 0x5662F44: MKL_get_N_Cores (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5662E17: mkl_serv_get_max_threads (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5C6F94C: mkl_lapack_dorgql (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6A7A25C: mkl_lapack_dorgtr (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6ABF0D6: mkl_lapack_dsyev (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x4FCEC58: DSYEV (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x4010D0: main (in /home/usrname/virtualscreen/ConfLib/org/a.out)
> ==13040==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
> ==13040== 
> ==13040== Invalid read of size 16
> ==13040==    at 0x7899C68: __intel_sse2_strlen (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/compiler/lib/intel64/libiomp5.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x78464B5: __kmp_env_blk_init (kmp_environment.c:536)
> ==13040==    by 0x786CE23: __kmp_asat_env_initialize(char const*) (kmp_settings.c:5198)
> ==13040==    by 0x7860497: __kmp_middle_initialize (kmp_runtime.c:7876)
> ==13040==    by 0x7847903: omp_get_num_procs (kmp_ftn_entry.h:497)
> ==13040==    by 0x5662F44: MKL_get_N_Cores (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5662E17: mkl_serv_get_max_threads (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5C6F94C: mkl_lapack_dorgql (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6A7A25C: mkl_lapack_dorgtr (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6ABF0D6: mkl_lapack_dsyev (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x4FCEC58: DSYEV (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x4010D0: main (in /home/usrname/virtualscreen/ConfLib/org/a.out)
> ==13040==  Address 0x8811440 is 48 bytes inside a block of size 58 alloc'd
> ==13040==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x8281C59: __add_to_environ (setenv.c:193)
> ==13040==    by 0x4C3277F: setenv (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x7846093: __kmp_env_set (kmp_environment.c:236)
> ==13040==    by 0x785EF8E: __kmp_register_library_startup() (kmp_runtime.c:7361)
> ==13040==    by 0x78601B4: __kmp_middle_initialize (kmp_runtime.c:7876)
> ==13040==    by 0x7847903: omp_get_num_procs (kmp_ftn_entry.h:497)
> ==13040==    by 0x5662F44: MKL_get_N_Cores (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5662E17: mkl_serv_get_max_threads (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5C6F94C: mkl_lapack_dorgql (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6A7A25C: mkl_lapack_dorgtr (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6ABF0D6: mkl_lapack_dsyev (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040== 
> ==13040== Invalid read of size 16
> ==13040==    at 0x7899C68: __intel_sse2_strlen (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/compiler/lib/intel64/libiomp5.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x7846557: __kmp_env_blk_init (kmp_environment.c:536)
> ==13040==    by 0x786CE23: __kmp_asat_env_initialize(char const*) (kmp_settings.c:5198)
> ==13040==    by 0x7860497: __kmp_middle_initialize (kmp_runtime.c:7876)
> ==13040==    by 0x7847903: omp_get_num_procs (kmp_ftn_entry.h:497)
> ==13040==    by 0x5662F44: MKL_get_N_Cores (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5662E17: mkl_serv_get_max_threads (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5C6F94C: mkl_lapack_dorgql (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6A7A25C: mkl_lapack_dorgtr (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6ABF0D6: mkl_lapack_dsyev (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x4FCEC58: DSYEV (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x4010D0: main (in /home/usrname/virtualscreen/ConfLib/org/a.out)
> ==13040==  Address 0x8811440 is 48 bytes inside a block of size 58 alloc'd
> ==13040==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x8281C59: __add_to_environ (setenv.c:193)
> ==13040==    by 0x4C3277F: setenv (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x7846093: __kmp_env_set (kmp_environment.c:236)
> ==13040==    by 0x785EF8E: __kmp_register_library_startup() (kmp_runtime.c:7361)
> ==13040==    by 0x78601B4: __kmp_middle_initialize (kmp_runtime.c:7876)
> ==13040==    by 0x7847903: omp_get_num_procs (kmp_ftn_entry.h:497)
> ==13040==    by 0x5662F44: MKL_get_N_Cores (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5662E17: mkl_serv_get_max_threads (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5C6F94C: mkl_lapack_dorgql (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6A7A25C: mkl_lapack_dorgtr (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6ABF0D6: mkl_lapack_dsyev (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040== 
> ==13040== Invalid read of size 16
> ==13040==    at 0x7899C68: __intel_sse2_strlen (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/compiler/lib/intel64/libiomp5.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x7845F52: __kmp_env_get (kmp_environment.c:127)
> ==13040==    by 0x785E88E: __kmp_internal_end_library (kmp_runtime.c:7164)
> ==13040==    by 0x7860B2D: __kmp_internal_end_atexit (kmp_runtime.c:6805)
> ==13040==    by 0x785BCC8: __kmp_internal_end_fini (kmp_runtime.c:6774)
> ==13040==    by 0x4010757: _dl_fini (dl-fini.c:257)
> ==13040==    by 0x8282258: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:82)
> ==13040==    by 0x82822A4: exit (exit.c:104)
> ==13040==    by 0x4011BB: main (in /home/usrname/virtualscreen/ConfLib/org/a.out)
> ==13040==  Address 0x8811440 is 48 bytes inside a block of size 58 alloc'd
> ==13040==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x8281C59: __add_to_environ (setenv.c:193)
> ==13040==    by 0x4C3277F: setenv (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x7846093: __kmp_env_set (kmp_environment.c:236)
> ==13040==    by 0x785EF8E: __kmp_register_library_startup() (kmp_runtime.c:7361)
> ==13040==    by 0x78601B4: __kmp_middle_initialize (kmp_runtime.c:7876)
> ==13040==    by 0x7847903: omp_get_num_procs (kmp_ftn_entry.h:497)
> ==13040==    by 0x5662F44: MKL_get_N_Cores (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5662E17: mkl_serv_get_max_threads (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x5C6F94C: mkl_lapack_dorgql (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6A7A25C: mkl_lapack_dorgtr (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040==    by 0x6ABF0D6: mkl_lapack_dsyev (in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so)
> ==13040== 
>  DSYEV Example Program Results
> 
>  Eigenvalues
>  -11.07  -6.23   0.86   8.87  16.09
> 
>  Eigenvectors (stored columnwise)
>   -0.30  -0.61   0.40  -0.37   0.49
>   -0.51  -0.29  -0.41  -0.36  -0.61
>   -0.08  -0.38  -0.66   0.50   0.40
>   -0.00  -0.45   0.46   0.62  -0.46
>   -0.80   0.45   0.17   0.31   0.16
> ==13040== 
> ==13040== HEAP SUMMARY:
> ==13040==     in use at exit: 38,628 bytes in 8 blocks
> ==13040==   total heap usage: 29 allocs, 21 frees, 44,066 bytes allocated
> ==13040== 
> ==13040== LEAK SUMMARY:
> ==13040==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==13040==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==13040==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==13040==    still reachable: 38,628 bytes in 8 blocks
> ==13040==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==13040== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
> ==13040== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
> ==13040== 
> ==13040== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
> ==13040== ERROR SUMMARY: 9 errors from 9 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with valgrind, but doesn't the leak summary  state that there is no memory leaked?

Comment: @dmg I was not sure why it happens. After reading Sebastian Stigler's answer, I know that mkl doesn't free its memory right away but waits until the program end. So there will seem to be a memory leak while the program is running but in the end there won't be any.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [memory leak when using intel mkl](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/memory-leak-when-using-intel-mkl). The gist of it is, that the librarry manages its memory by itself which may leed tools like valgrind to report memoryleaks although there are none.

Comment: thank you. I'm new to mkl so there are many things I don't know.